# personalize the output with Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to mine some data with Rstudio, but I have problem in the results output.

- Trying to search big number from `100000 to 900000` the function works well but the output of the result is coded in 4 bits. It looks like this `(X9438)`
- Also, I mentioned that this result `a.12458a>a` is shown like this `a.12458a.a`

I tried to extract the output into an external file thinking that the terms will be shown in it original format, but in vain.

Is there any package, configuration or plugin to add to resolve this problem?

Comment: Is your question about how to control how many digits are printed? If so, have you tried specifying how many digits you would like to displayed with options(digits=10)?

Comment: and what about the special character printing (the >)

Comment: Please include some sample data and the code you used to generate this issue, it is not clear what went wrong exactly and what are you looking to do.